# How does logical negation work in C?

Tags: c

I have been using ! (logical negation) in C and in other languages, I am curious does anyone know how to make your own ! function? or have a creative way of making one?

Comment: When you talk about a "! method", it sounds like you may be talking about C++. You can write a function that does logical negation in C, but you cannot override the ! operator. C++ allows you to write an operator! - either a method or a non-member function - but that's C++, not C.

Comment: It wasn't as easy as I'd thought to find a Q&A with the part of the standard saying that `!` returns 1 if the input is 0 (as opposed to any other non-zero value in a compiler-dependent fashion), but it's [C99 standard 6.5.3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945950/is-logical-negation-of-zero-0-compiler-dependent-in-c).  Just FYI.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
int my_negate(int x)
{
    return x == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Happens all the time to me.  I'll write something, but actually meant the exact opposite.

Comment: I don't think this works in all cases.  I don't think there's any guarantee about the value when a null pointer value is transformed to an `int`.  There's very little in the Standards I'm familiar with other than that a pointer can be cast to an integral type, and a constant integral expression with value zero will be cast to a null pointer value.

Comment: Null pointers are always converted to integer value zero (even if the null pointer is not represented like that). (Harbison & Steele, §6.2.3)

Comment: Doesn't `==0` do the job? The `? 1 : 0` part could be omitted.

Comment: Pascal: `==0` would indeed do the job; the `? 1 : 0` part just makes it more clear what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

`!e` can be replaced by `((e)?0:1)`

Answer (score 5):

Remember the bang operator '!' or exclamation mark in english parlance, is built into the programming language as a means to negate.

Consider this ternary operator example:

```
(some condition) ? true : false;
```

Now, if that was negated, the ternary operator would be this

```
(some condition) ? false : true;
```

The common area where that can get some programmers in a bit of a fit is the `strcmp` function, which returns 0 for the strings being the same, and 1 for two strings not the same:

```
if (strcmp(foo, "foo")){

}
```

When really it should be:

```
if (!strcmp(foo, "foo")){
}
```

In general when you negate, it is the opposite as shown in the ternary operator example...

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'strcmp' returns 0 for strings the same; it returns a negative number (not necessarily -1) if the first string precedes the second, and a positive number (not necessarily +1) if the first string follows the second - where the ordering is based on the byte values of the (unsigned) characters that compose the strings.

Comment: @Jonathan: Correct, -1 is considered to be true.....as it is the max unsigned int...i.e. 0xFFFF...i.e. non-zero, regardless when -'ive or +'ive

Comment: Your answer states 'the strcmp function, which returns 0 for the strings being the same, and 1 for two strings not the same'.  This is incorrect; it returns a non-zero value for two strings that are not the same, not 'unconditionally 1 if the strings are different'.

Answer (score 3):

C considers all non-zero values "true" and zero "false".  Logical negation is done by checking against zero.  If the input is exactly zero, output a non-zero value; otherwise, output zero.  In code, you can write this as `(input == 0) ? 1 : 0` (or you can convert it into an `if` statement).

When you ask how to "make your own ! method", do you mean you want to write a function that negates a logic value or do you want to define what the exclamation-point operator does?  If the former, then the statement I posted above should suffice.  If the latter, then I'm afraid this is something that can't be done in C.  C++ supports operator overloading, and if doing this is a strict necessity then I would suggest looking there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overload an operator, the proper prototype is:

```
bool operator!();
```

I'm not a big fan of overloading operators, but some people like their syntactic sugar.
EDIT: This is C++ only! Put it in the definition of your class.

Comment: Overloading operators works well with templates.  Just make sure your `operator!()` has the same semantics as `!`.

Comment: If you put it in the class definition, it takes no arguments and operates on *this.  bool operator!() const; The prototype you show could be used for a friend operator definition.

Comment: Right. Good use case for overloading an operator. If you didn't have a good reason like that, however, the operator isn't usually as intuitive as a well-named function. There's always exceptions, though.