# What does !!(x) mean in C (esp. the Linux kernel)?

Tags: c, gcc

I've been reading through the Linux kernel (specifically, 2.6.11).
I came across the following definition:

```
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
```

(from linux-2.6.11/include/linux/compiler.h:61 [lxr link](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.11/include/linux/compiler.h#L61))

What does !! accomplish? Why not just use (x)?

> #### See also:
>
> - [How does logical negation work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319766/how-does-logical-negation-work-in-c)
> - [Double Negation in C++ code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168406/what-does-double-exclamation-point-mean

Comment: @Joel Potter, looks like you're right. I had searched for C rather than C++...

Comment: @Joel: those questions relate to C++ and Perl, respectively. While C++ is at least close, in practice the uses are at least somewhat different due to C having no built-in boolean type!

Comment: @Shog9, true. But that difference seems small in common usage. If nobody else agrees than this question will stay open. ;-)

Comment: This is the commit message that introduced the double negation: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tglx/history.git/commit/?id=2e0623e3e0d76e796aaa1ff2f7891bc7d43ebca2

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`!!(x)` forces it to be either 0 or 1. 0 remains 0, but any non-zero value (which would be 'true' in a boolean context) becomes 1.

Comment: It's really not necessary in this case since we expect the result to be 0. It's really only necessary for the `#define likely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)` to ensure that true is 1. It's likely only included in the `unlikely` definition for symmetry.

Comment: How interesting, I have previously used `x&&1` (or `x&&YES` in ObjC) for this. Never thought to use `!!`.

Answer (score 11):

It's not so much a language syntax but a common shorthand for converting a char or int into quasi-boolean.

In C logical operations such as == && ! and so on can act on int, char etc, as there is no boolean type, however according to the standard they are guaranteed to return 0 for False and 1 for true.

So for example if you have

```
int x = 5;
```

you can force it to convert to a "boolean" type (there is no boolean type in C hence the quotes) you do

```
x = !x; /* !5 which gives 0 always */
x = !x; /* which gives 1 always */
```

Comment: In fact C does have a Boolean type. `_Bool` was introduced in C99, with a macro `bool` in `<stdbool.h>` expanding to `_Bool`. But the built-in logical operators like `==`, `&&`, `!`, et al still yield results of type `int` with the value `0` or `1`.

Comment: "however according to the standard they are guaranteed to return 0 for False and 1 for true."  Are you sure?  I thought any non-zero was true, which allows for compiler optimizations that return non-1 values to mean "true".

Answer (score 9):

`!!(x)` is equivalent to `(x) != 0` (unless some very oddball operator overloading is going on in C++).

The fact that it's not obvious what `!!(x)` is doing is a probably a good reason to use `(x) != 0`.  Unless you want to be an elite kernel hacker.

<s>See [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520381/why-does-expression-with-double-signs-need-to-die-c-closed) (if it's still around) for a discussion of the merits of `!!` (maybe that question will be be reopened, since this question indicates that it has some value).</s>

Comment: It's "not obvious" what `!!(x)` does for half a second the first time you see it. After you see it and either a) think about it for a bit or b) ask someone else, you'll recognize what the `!!` "operator" does quite quickly.

Comment: @Chris - if it's a common idiom in your shop, it's probably OK to use it. On the other hand, I come across `!!(x)` infrequently enough that I have to pause for a moment to grok it. I don't have to cipher for a moment about what `(x) != 0` means.  Not a huge deal, but I see little to recommend `!!(x)` over `(x) != 0`.

Comment: Fair enough. I rather like the way it looks, but there isn't really a compelling argument for using it over `(x) != 0` (unless you need to rely on some objects overloading `!` to evaluate them in boolean contexts).