# NOT of an integer in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;

    i=1;
    printf("%d ",!i);

    i=5;
    printf("%d ",!i);

    i=0;
    printf("%d\n",!i);

    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output in C: `0 0 1`

What is the logic behind the output?

Comment: the logic is `0 == false` and `anything else == true`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319766/how-does-logical-negation-work-in-c

Answer (score 7):

In C, any non zero value is considered to be a true value. So taking the logical negation with `!` converts it to `0`. The logical negation of `0` is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

In C booleans are integers where 0 is `false` and any other value is `true`.

`!` is NOT (as you know) so it turns any value that is not 0 into 0 and it turns 0 into 1.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is used like a boolean value:

- If `i != 0`, then `!i == 0`.
- If `i == 0`, then `!i == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "logic"?

The specific behavior of `!` operator? It is defined by the language standard. It produces `0` for non-zero argument. And `1` for zero argument. That's the way it is defined.

The rationale behind such definition? Well, it is supposed to implement the `logical-not` behavior. Historically, in C language logical "false" is represented by zero integer values, while everything non-zero is interpreted as logical "true". So, that's what you observe in your experiment. When `!` operator (or any other logical operator in C) has to generate a "true" result, it uses `1` to represent it, not just some arbitrary non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a Boolean operation. The '!' is NOT an inverter as one would normally think of it. If you are looking for the inverter, use the '~'.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is a boolean operator that inverts the given input, from true to false and false to true.
True is anything that is not zero. False is zero. So, when you `not`ted `1` or `5`, you invert a true value, which prints the integer value of false, 0. Next when you invert a false value, it prints the integer value of true (default 1)