# How does `if(!found)` in this function work?

Tags: c

This function finds the first and last occurrence of an integer in an array. I don't understand what the second if statement does `if(!found)` is it the same as saying `if(found==0)`? How does the second statement 'find' the first occurrence? Lets say if there are 3 4's in an array the loop finds the last occurrence and sets it to `plast` and than it goes into the 2nd if statement how does it know to find the first occurrence and not the 2nd occurrence?

```
find_occurences(const int a[], size_t n, int x, size_t *pfirst, size_t *plast) {
        size_t i;
int found = 0;
for(i=0; i<; i++) 
    if (a[i] == x) 
        *plast = i;
        if (!found) {
            *pfirst = i;
            found = 1; 
        }
    }
    return found;
```

}

Comment: Either there are missing brackets or there is weird indentation going on at the first `if` statement. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Yeah, also can't see `foundlast` declaration, i assume the brackets should start after the first `if` and ends after the second `if`

Comment: Also, `foundlast = 0;` is it a part of first `if()` condition? Right now it is getting executed irrespective of what first `if()` is evaluated as. Depending upon your logic, you have either missed a `{` and `}` with the first `if()` condition, *or* indented the code in a confusing way.

Comment: You might try reading a basic C tutorial before attempting to program in it. There you will learn about elementary things like the `!` (not) operator.

Comment: Sorry guys I dont know how it got messed up like that i just fixed the code

Comment: @JohnDough Still won't compile. The middle part of `for(i=0; i<; i++) ` looks weird and you have three `}` but just two `{`

Answer (score 4):

In `C`, `0` means `boolean false`, and any other *non zero* values are treated as `boolean true`.

So, `if (!found)` will go to *true* path if `found = 0`.

> `if(!found)` is it the same as saying `if(found==0)`?

Yes it is!

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe your source should look like this:

```
find_occurences(const int a[], size_t n, int x, size_t *pfirst, size_t *plast)
{
    size_t i;
    int found = 0; 

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) // go through all items from first to last
    {
        if (a[i] == x) // if the item is the searched one ...
        {
            *plast = i; // mark as last (every time one is found)
            //foundlast = 0; not needed
            if (!found) // if there hasn't been one found yet ...
            {
                *pfirst = i; // mark as first
                found = 1; // will never enter this if again, thus only on first
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you had some copy-paste errors.

And to address your main question: All non-zero values in C yield `true` in an `if`-statement.

I'd suggest taking a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319766/how-does-logical-negation-work-in-c) for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand what is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

In C

```
if(!found){
    //This statements works only when "found" equal to 0
}
```

In contrary

```
if(found){
   //This statement works only when "found" not equal to 0
}
```

In c++ we can use bool as a Boolean variable... Now suppose

```
bool found
if(!found){
//This statement works when found = false;
}
```